# Consume SOAP service using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service using PHP. I'd prefer to use cURL, however PHP-SOAP is also an option.

I have en example:

Endpoint: https://devpoints.ex.com:8443/UserSystem.svc/basic

Headers:

```
POST /UserSystem.svc/basic HTTP/1.1
Host: devpoints.ex.com:8443
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Basic OWRWXHVhdGpkc3BvcnRzKmFXakNrOUNYNTg4bzRZakFSePWq
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IUserSystemInterface/GetCurrentPointConfiguration
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cph="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dev.UserBank.WebServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetCurrentPointConfiguration>
         <tem:header>
           <cph:SystemInstance>myshopname</cph:SystemInstance>
         </tem:header>
      </tem:GetCurrentPointConfiguration>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

From the above I have tried the following, which returns a 202:

```
$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:cph="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dev.UserBank.WebServices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetCurrentPointConfiguration>
         <tem:header>
           <cph:SystemInstance>myshop</cph:SystemInstance>
         </tem:header>
      </tem:GetCurrentPointConfiguration>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://devpoints.ex.com:8443/UserSystem.svc/basic');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'POST /UserSystem.svc/basic HTTP/1.1',
  'Host: devpoints.ex.com:8443',
  'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
  'Authorization: Basic OWRWXHVhdGpkc3BvcnRzKmFXakNrOUNYNTg4bzRZakFSePWq',
  'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IUserSystemInterface/GetCurrentPointConfiguration',
  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $xml ),
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

So... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong since I get a 202 returned?

Comment: Any status code in the 2XX range means successful. 202, from the wiki, means accepted, but it could be slightly different for whatever API you are using. You should check your API's documentation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Not much help from the documentation. The documentation states: "Synchronous: This call is read only and can be repeatedly called from a queing caller" and then there a table containing a list of properties on the returned object. In the "Fault" list there is only one cause, "empty" - which is excatly what I get in return along with the 202, nada :/

Comment: What do you expect it to return? It sounds like 202 is equal to boolean true. It means you don't need anything in response (like say a JSON object ), you only need to know if the operation was successful or not, which is was.

Comment: Like I wrote, the documentation has a table-list of properties that should be returned - so I expect an object :)

Comment: Documentation link?

Comment: Corporate stuff... I can screenshot it?

Comment: Fine with me. I just want to see that one call.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/nwmsg2rvp/

Comment: Sorry but everything looks fine to me. I would contact the service provider.